# tintcolor of a custom uibutton resetting to the default tintcolor for a specific view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, stripe-payments, tintcolor

I have a ViewController with a custom control [stripe/PaymentKit](https://github.com/stripe/PaymentKit)  in it, also there's a custom made UIButton whose tintcolor is set to green by me.
The problem is that the ptkview somehow changes the tintcolor of my uibutton to the default tintcolor of the uiwindow while the library has no tintcolor code. Has anyone faced the same issue before ?

Comment: Can you share some sort of your code?

Comment: Is it the save button?

Comment: Where you able to fix this issue?